# jquery preview image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to implement a preview button so that when my users clicks on the upload button image they could have a preview but the thing is that it is not working, I wonder why ?? A brief description : I have a js function that creates new elements and append it to a p tag date. It is in this function that is going to create the preview image code

```js
// code for creating new elements
function createElements(){

 const userQuestions = document.querySelector('#userQuestions');
   userQuestions.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend', '<div class="uploader" onclick="$(\'#filePhoto\').click()"><p id="bg-text">No image</p></div><input type="file" name="userprofile_picture"  id="filePhoto" style="display:block;width:185px;"  /></center><div class="grid-container">'
  );
 
 
 
}



///Code to preview image 
function handleImage(e) {
      var imageLoader = document.getElementById('filePhoto');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        
        $('.uploader').html( '<img width="300px" height="350px" src="'+event.target.result+'"/>' );
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```css
.uploader {width:50%;height:35%;background:#f3f3f3;border:2px dashed #0091ea;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="userQuestions"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="createElements()">add elements</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run the snippet above you can see that the button is woeking but the preview is not showing. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of jQuery -- particularly using

1. [event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
2. [delegated event handlers](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation) for dynamically-created elements
3. [tree traversal methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

```js
$(function() {

  var userQuestions = $('#userQuestions');

  // create onclick event handler for your button
  $('#addElements').click(function() {
    // IDs must be unique - since you can have an arbitrary number of filePhoto, use a class instead
    userQuestions.append(
      '<div class="uploader"><p id="bg-text">No image</p></div><input type="file" name="userprofile_picture" class="filePhoto" /><div class="grid-container"></div>'
    );

  });

  // create delegated onclick event handler for your .uploader 
  userQuestions.on('click', '.uploader', function() {
    // you only want to target the file input immediately after it
    $(this).next('[type=file]').click();
  });


  // create delegated onchange event handler for your .filePhoto
  userQuestions.on('change', '.filePhoto', function() {
    // find related uploader
    var uploader = $(this).prev('.uploader');
    // check file was given
    if (this.files && this.files.length) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        uploader.html('<img width="300px" height="350px" src="' + event.target.result + '"/>');
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.uploader {
  width: 50%;
  height: 35%;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border: 2px dashed #0091ea;
}

.filePhoto {
  display: block;
  width: 185px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="userQuestions"></div>
  <!-- added ID attribute -->
  <button type="button" id="addElements">add elements</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit**

This answer is a non-jQuery solution based off your comment.

```js
// code for creating new elements
function createElements() {
  // no need to document.querySelector if the selector is an ID
  const userQuestions = document.getElementById('userQuestions');
  // you want to use onclick/onchange attributes here as they are dynamically created
  userQuestions.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend', '<div class="uploader" onclick="selectFile(this)"><p id="bg-text">No image</p></div><input type="file" name="userprofile_picture" onchange="handleImage(this)" />'
  );
}

// trigger click on file input that follows the uploader
function selectFile(uploader) {
  uploader.nextSibling.click();
}

///Code to preview image 
function handleImage(input) {
  if (input.files.length) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      input.previousSibling.innerHTML =
        '<img width="300px" height="350px" src="' + e.target.result + '"/>';
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
.uploader {
  width: 50%;
  height: 35%;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border: 2px dashed #0091ea;
}

.filePhoto {
  display: block;
  width: 185px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="userQuestions"></div>

  <button type="button" onclick="createElements()">add elements</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is very nice I appreciate it ! :D but the problem with my app is that there are a bunch of code in the function createElements() that I cannot omit it :( removing the createElement function is not an option, I tried to modify your code to put it in function but it is not working. Thank you man i really appreciate the support.

Comment: Thant's it !! Thank you so much !! heheheh yay!

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Company Logo</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" value="" name="companyLogo" id="companyLogo" accept="image/*" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="displayImage">
     <img id="imgData" src="#" alt="your image" height="150px" width="150px" />
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#companyLogo").change(function(e) {
  if(e.target.value === "") {
    $("#displayImage").hide();
  } else {
    $("#displayImage").show();
  }
  readURL(this);
});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $("#imgData").attr("src", e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short n simple**

No need to create an element on click.
Just add an image tag and set a default image like no image selected or something like that.

The following code will help you

```
<input type="file" name="myCutomfile" id="myCutomfile"/>


<img id="customTargetImg" src="default.jpg" width="400" height="250">

$("#myCutomfile").change(function() {    
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#customTargetImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```